# WCF error: Could not find default endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I implemented a WCF web service and I want to try it on a Console client app. I added a reference to the service but i get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract 'WorkWS.IService1' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.'

**UPDATED ALL Web.config**
This is part of my Web.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;;Initial Catalog=FirstProject; User Id = aykut ; password= ***</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="HBM_ASSEMBLY" value="BusinessEntities" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />

  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="WebService.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

  <dependentAssembly>

    <assemblyIdentity name="Iesi.Collections" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />

  </dependentAssembly>

</assemblyBinding>
```

And that is my Tester namespace WStester2:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Name = "dsfsfsdf";
        c.SurName="asdass";
        c.Age = 12;
        client.CreateCustomer(c);
    }
}
```

And this is my WCF web service namespace : WebService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Customer CreateCustomer(Customer customer);
}
```

I think I should organize my app.config on Tester but I don't know how it can be done, so default app.config file is this:

```
   <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
   </configuration>
```

Thanx for advice guys.

Comment: Did you configure to have multiple startup projects, so that when console app is running, WCF is running also

Comment: Yes,but i try to new solution for simple wcf and test. I get a same error

Comment: I found in one old solution that i did have  web.config bindings also in  app.config in test project, probably did add service reference to service project

Comment: What should i do MRsa?

Answer (score 1):

I organize to my app.config file and solve the problem 
And Sure that **WorkWS is my reference name**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://*MyIpaddress*/Service1.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
      contract="WorkWS.IService1" name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```